# PHP ask password before delete

Tags: php, mysql

I want a web application to ask for the password before deleting. The procedure I created is, before clicking the delete button, a modal will appear and ask for the password for security.

Here is my source code:

```
<?php
   session_start();
    require 'database.php';
    $id = 0;

    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }



?>

             <?php

             if(isset($_POST['login']))
              { 
                $password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST["password"], "/\'\"\;"));
                $msg = '';

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_user where password = '$password'");
                   {
                    while($rwOK = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                    {
                      $_SESSION['password'] = $rwOK['password']; 
                    }   
                    if( $_SESSION['password']==$passsowrd)
                    {
                      include 'database.php';
                      $pdo = Database::connect();
                      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC';
                      foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row)
                      {
                      header("Location: delete_member.php?id=$row[id]");
                      }
                    }
                    else if(empty($password))
                    {
                      $msg =  '<i><font color="red">Please input Administrator password.</font></i>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      //$_SESSION['tae'] = $tae;
                      $msg = '<i><font color="red">Invalid Password</font></i>';
                    }
                  }
                }



                ?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Stock Employee </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<!-- modal -->
<!-- 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- -->

<body>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Delete Record</h3>
                    </div>

                    <!-- <form class="form-horizontal" action="delete.php" method="post"> -->
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
                      <p class="alert alert-error">Are you sure to delete ?</p>
                      <?php echo !empty($passwordError)?'error':'';?>
                      <div class="form-actions">

                          <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button> -->

                          <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Yes</button>

                          <!-- Modal -->
                              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">

                                  <!-- Modal content-->
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                      <h4 class="modal-title">Administrator Access</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">                                  

                                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($passwordError)?'error':'';?>">
                                        <label class="control-label">Password :</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input name="password" type="password"  placeholder="username" required value="<?php echo !empty($password)?$password:'';?>">
                                            <?php if (!empty($passwordError)): ?>
                                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $passwordError;?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="control-group">
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>                               
                                        </div>
                                      </div>                                     

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="login">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>

                                </div>
                              </div>

                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">No</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled $password variable

```
if( $_SESSION['password']==$passsowrd)
{
```

Should be

```
if( $_SESSION['password']==$password)
{
```

Also isnt good to iterate over the entire customers table when you are going to delete just a record, use a where clause to get the record and delete if exists, notice type casting to avoid SQL injection.

```
   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = '.(int) $id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but it's still not working ? hmm

Comment: add the **value** attribute to the Delete button otherwise you get NULL on $_POST['login']

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="login" value="login">Delete</button>`